# Is the telemetry for the Surveyor moon missions still existent?

Tags: the-moon

Is the telemetry for the Surveyor moon missions still existent?

Between 1966 and 1968 NASA put on the surface of the Moon five [Surveyor](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/surveyor.htm) landers. Is the telemetry for these mission still available somewhere in archives? I do not refer only to pictures but also to all data the probes transmitted back to the Earth.

[image]
Surveyor 3 [NASA]

Answer (score 3):

NASA publishes the scientific data from each mission at the [NASA Space Science Data Coordinated Archive](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/).

The Surveyor start page is [here](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/lunar/surveyor.html).

Parts of the NSSDCA are offline today, so I can't see the data collections themselves, but it looks like most of the data is there.

The nonscientific data (telemetry related to spacecraft operations) may not have been published. The only missions I recall the telemetry being published for is the Apollo missions. 
Even if it hasn't been published, it's probably still in a NASA archive, it'd just take a bit more trouble to track it down and request access.

Comment: Here is the problem. I have searched for the Apollo missions telemetry and found this article: "Moon landing tapes got erased, NASA admits | Reuters" (July 20, 2009).

Comment: You weren't asking for Apollo telemetry, you wanted to know about Surveyor.

Comment: ugh, all those Surveyor pages end in 404 not found errors.  NASA, you are not helping.

Comment: "Aside from a few canisters of Apollo 9 telemetry tapes still stored at the WNRC, the Apollo-era telemetry tapes no longer exist-anywhere." (Source: https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/Apollo_11_TV_Tapes_Report.pdf). I hope that the telemetry for the Surveyor missions did not have the same fate.

Comment: That is *only* about the Apollo 11 telemetry tapes.

Comment: I also do not find the telemetry for Apollo 8, 10, 12-17. There is no trace of it.

Comment: "not available on a website" is not the same as "does not exist any more"